# how to send message to http tunnet(using netty.jar) in java from node.js(using EverSocket.js module)

Tags: java, node.js, port

my server is in java which is written in http tunnel (not in web socket) using netty.jar 
and my client in node.js(using EverSocket.js module).i want to send client information such mac address to server. the sample code is here

Comment: Server code is written in java using netty.jar and client in node.js using everSocket.js

Comment: How i put here the sample code of client and server